# Add Block Before Entry Title Using PHP

Tags: php, functions, block-editor

I'm using this code to add a block before the entry title on the front page but its not working:

```
$e      = get_block( '552' ); 
$eblock = apply_filters( 'the_content', $e->post_content );

echo $eblock;
```

**Note :** The code works fine within the content area but not outside the loop.

I also tried do_blocks() but it prints multiple instances of the output which is form HTML.

```
$get_block = get_post( '552' );
$footer = $get_block->post_content; 
$out = do_blocks($footer);

return $title .  $out;
```

Here's where i got the reusable block ID http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=552&action=edit

It must have something to do with add_filter('the_title', i'm using because it works fine when i echo it without a hook.

Comment: There's no function called `get_block()`. What is `'552'`? What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: 552 is the ID for the reusable block which i want to output using PHP. See update

Comment: There's a get_block() on WP_REST_Block_Types_Controller but you can't mean that. Where does that function come from?

Comment: From a discussion on the WordPress forums

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out. The code for the_title filter was causing the problem so i added the code to the entry header template part and it works fine.

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field('post_content', '552' ) );
```